# LookUpEdit does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, lookup

I have XtraTabControl with two pages, both of them has one LookUpEdit,
when page load which on the secondpage does not work,

```
void Frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lookUpEditA.Properties.DataSource = datasource. . . . .
    lookUpEditA.Properties.ValueMember = "ID";
    lookUpEditA.Properties.DisplayMember = "xxxx";
    lookUpEditA.Properties.PopulateColumns();
    lookUpEditA.Properties.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;

    lookUpEditB.Properties.DataSource = datasource. . . . .
    lookUpEditB.Properties.ValueMember = "ID";
    lookUpEditB.Properties.DisplayMember = "xxxx";
    lookUpEditB.Properties.PopulateColumns();
    lookUpEditB.Properties.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work".

Comment: need more details as well...not just what the failure is, but I dont really even understand the setup

Answer (score 1):

I can see the issue only with setting visibility of 'ID' column on second LookUpEdit.

The reason of this issue is that the LookUpEdit can't operate with datasource representation (perform populating columns, operating with column's visibility and etc.) until it's handle been created. The second LookUpEdit will create it's handle only when the second tab page has been shown.

To avoid the issue you can use the following approach:

```
if(!lookUpEditB.IsHandleCreated)
    lookUpEditB.HandleCreated += lookUpEditB_HandleCreated;
else InitLookUpEditDataSource();
//...
void lookUpEditB_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    lookUpEditB.HandleCreated -= lookUpEditB_HandleCreated;
    InitLookUpEditDataSource();
}
void InitLookUpEditDataSource() {
    lookUpEditB.Properties.DataSource = this.categoriesBindingSource;
    lookUpEditB.Properties.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
    lookUpEditB.Properties.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
    lookUpEditB.Properties.PopulateColumns();
    lookUpEditB.Properties.Columns["CategoryID"].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DmitryG said, you can not use `lookUpEditB.Properties.PopulateColumns()` statement until control's UI handlers are not created.

As per my understanding these are created  only when the second tab page shown. Except creating conditional statement to create handlers etc, you can use the [`XtraTabControl.SelectedPageChanged Event`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_SelectedPageChangedtopic) where you can bind the data source of the `lookUpEditB` by checking condition that [`XtraTabControl.SelectedTabPage Property`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_SelectedTabPagetopic) is set with **Page2** which contain the `lookUpEditB`.

Check the tested Code Snippet below:

```
public partial class TabControlTest : Form
{
    List<Category> dataSource = new List<Category>();
    public TabControlTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dataSource.Add(new Category { ID = i + 1, Name = "Category" + (i + 1) });
        }
    }

    private void TabControlTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lookUpEditA.Properties.DataSource = dataSource;
        lookUpEditA.Properties.ValueMember = "ID";
        lookUpEditA.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
        lookUpEditA.Properties.PopulateColumns();
        lookUpEditA.Properties.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
    }

    private void xtraTabControl1_SelectedPageChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTab.TabPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage == xtraTabPage2)
        {
             lookUpEditB.Properties.DataSource = dataSource;
            lookUpEditB.Properties.ValueMember = "ID";
            lookUpEditB.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
            lookUpEditB.Properties.PopulateColumns();
            lookUpEditB.Properties.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.